Database rename causing wrong database to be queried
So I have 3 databases (BusinessLogic, DataStore and DataStore2) and basically restore DataStore2 from backup then rotate the database names so that in the end DataStore becomes DataStore2 and DataStore2 becomes DataStore.
All the queries in BusinessLogic reference DataStore.
If I have cached plans from queries run in the BusinessLogic databse and perform the database swap over any queries will follow the dbid around and not the database name meaning that DataStore2 is being queried (I can confirm this by setting the DataStore2 database offline and seeing errors)  even though everything I have found so far in the query plan says it is querying DataStore. Is this expected functionality?
Solutuions to this appear to be to the the following against the BusinessLogic database:
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB
or
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE
Is this the only way as it seems a little extreme?

If you're restoring from a backup and suddenly running the queries against completely different data, don't you want fresh plans for everything anyway? I would. (I would also see if the behavior is different between sp_renamedb, which might be what you're using currently, and using ALTER DATABASE to modify the name - which might have better hooks to broadcast the event.)

I might also consider using synonyms to make the shift, and instead of DataStore/DataStore2, use _yyyymmdd in the database name. In BusinessLogic you have CREATE SYNONYM dbo.SomeTableName FOR DataStore_20240410.dbo.SomeTableName. When you restore the next copy of DataStore, you call it DataStore_20240411. Then you change all the synonyms in BusinessLogic to point at the new database (and drop the old one).

I have mocked the process with ALTER DATABSE and have the same issue as sp_renamedb.
The 2 databases are an incremental of each other. So 99.9%+ of the data will be identical which is why clearing the plans was going to be a last resort.

The synonyms might be a longer implementation process due to related additional jobs that are performed after restore and before the switch in however that is another avenue of investigation. Thank you.

"any queries will follow the dbid around and not the database name meaning that DataStore2 is being queried even though everything I have found so far in the query plan says it is querying DataStore. Is this expected functionality?" why would you think otherwise? The query plan is certainly cached by the actual database, not the name, otherwise it couldn't be used again. The database name is just a user-friendly name to access it, the server always identifies it by dbid
